# how to draw pie chart in ios

Tags: objective-c, pie-chart

I'M new in ios i don't know how to draw pie chart in our project using code here is my response:

```
1^Altiva^20^50`25`10`10`5^50%`25%`10%`10%`5%^Title 1`Title 2`Title 3`Title 4`Title 5^BD814F`4D50C0`006600`008800`002200^200^200@2002,
1^Covance^20^30`20`10`10`30^30%`20%`10%`10%`30%^Title 1`Title 2`Title 3`Title 4`Title 5^BD814F`4D50C0`006600`008800`002200^200^200@2003,
1^Storvas^20^35`35`10`10`10^35%`35%`10%`10%`10%^Title 1`Title 2`Title 3`Title 4`Title 5^BD814F`4D50C0`006600`008800`002200^200^200@2004,
1^Rosuvas^20^50`25`10`10`5^50%`25%`10%`10%`5%^Title 1`Title 2`Title 3`Title 4`Title 5^BD814F`4D50C0`006600`008800`002200^200^200@2005,
1^Ceruvin^20^50`25`10`10`5^50%`25%`10%`10%`5%^Title 1`Title 2`Title 3`Title 4`Title 5^BD814F`4D50C0`006600`008800`002200^200^200@2006,
1^Others^20^50`25`10`10`5^50%`25%`10%`10%`5%^Title 1`Title 2`Title 3`Title 4`Title 5^BD814F`4D50C0`006600`008800`002200^200^200@2007,
1^All^20^50`25`10`10`5^50%`25%`10%`10%`5%^Title 1`Title 2`Title 3`Title 4`Title 5^BD814F`4D50C0`006600`008800`002200^200^200
)
```

Whatever the data i' m geting here in that on the basis of Altiva and same line there percentage value i want to draw pie chart and this.

Can anyone help me in that ?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain the mess of code in your question? What does it mean, which bits are the bits that define the pie chart? etc... You might want to look at CorePlot though. https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot

Comment: cap split[4] th positon on the basis of this value  i want to draw the piechart .